# How can you query for something in Rails only if a variable is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider this query: `@colleges = College.where(category: @university_type).where("us_news_ranking <= ? AND size <= ?", @rank, @enrollment)`.

I'm using it for an advanced search, where I want to allow users to filter for certain criteria. I have the user fill out a form where all the fields are optional. If the user doesn't specify what size he's looking for, the `@enrollment` variable doesn't get defined. In that case, I don't want the query to query for size. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@colleges = College.where(category: @university_type)
@colleges = @colleges.where("us_news_ranking <= ?", @rank) unless @rank.blank?
@colleges = @colleges.where("size <= ?", @enrollment) unless @enrollment.blank?
```

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know that you could call `where` on a variable.

Comment: @colleges is a ActiveRelation object